# Mercurial: Uncommitted local changes are detected while there are none

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

Hi to all mercurial pros,

I'm facing a very strange issue with Mercurial. There's a repo with 2 heads. If I clone it, update to one of the heads and try to merge the other, it refuses because of uncommitted local changes. How can that be with a freshly cloned repo? Hg status does not show anything, hg commit says there are no changes. Furthermore, if I force the merge and try to commit afterwards, it tells me that it cannot because of missing files. Hg status still shows nothing, hg commit says there are 21 missing files, but does not list them. I'm absolutely out of ideas, would be happy to hear any.

Mercurial version: 6.6.3 (TortoiseHg), no extensions active except standard
OS: Win10 and 11

```
C:\Users\ar\judo> hg clone -U docs docsclone

C:\Users\ar\judo> cd docsclone

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg log -G

o  changeset:   13:00e42bc1d80c
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      11:2636897b57e0
|  user:        alre
|  date:        Sat Mar 16 23:40:29 2024 +0100
|  summary:     fixed DT handling in results export script
|
| o  changeset:   12:258250141287
|/   user:        indo
|    date:        Sat Mar 16 23:36:59 2024 +0100
|    summary:     JMP 2024 done + results exported
|
o  changeset:   11:2636897b57e0
|  user:        alre
|  date:        Fri Mar 15 23:03:43 2024 +0100
|  summary:     prepared tournament files JMP 2024 
|

... (clipped)

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg update 13
4404 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg merge 12
abort: uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg status

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg status --all
C .hgignore
... (clipped; shows all Clean)

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg commit
nothing changed (21 missing files, see 'hg status')

C:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg purge --all

c:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg update null
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 4383 files removed, 0 files unresolved

c:\Users\ar\judo\docsclone>hg update 13
4404 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Comment: If you try `hg purge` does that reveal anything useful?  (https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/PurgeExtension)

Comment: Hi StayOnTarget,
Thanks for your reply. No, it doesn't output anything. Tried `hg purge -p --all`, too.

Comment: If you clone to another PC, does it reproduce there?

Comment: Can you edit the post and add the exact error messages etc. that HG is printing out?  Maybe there is some other explanation that could be revealed by seeing the details.

Comment: I've added some command line output to the original question. Unfortunately I couldn't get more information out of hg. 
The behaviour could be reproduced on 2 other Windows machines. I'll try in a Ubuntu VM later.

Comment: Could there be something committed and modified that is also in the .hgignore file?

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait, I coundn't find the time yesterday to answer.
I don't think it's related to hgignore. If I delete it, then it's the only change I see on commit.
Interestingly the problem does not occur on linux. I tried yesterday on a Ubuntu and could merge without problems.

Comment: Since it doesn't happen on Linux, I'm guessing it could be some file with a capitalization difference. Maybe there is an inconsistency within HG how that is handled, since Windows is case-preserving but not case-comparing, but linux is just plain case-sensitive.  You might have to look through your files manually to see what you can find.

Comment: Maybe you can use Windows Subsystem for Linux just to try and identify the problem

Comment: Could be. I'm somewhat suspicious now that it could also be a path length issue. Although there are no paths longer than 250 now, some are close. So maybe the 21 missing files originate from hg update trying to checkout files with longer paths.

Comment: Good guess... You can move the entire repository folder to say c:\ as a test for that.

Comment: Did that. The problem is still there, but I found something else interesting:

V:\d>hg update tip
4404 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

V:\d>hg update null
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 4383 files removed, 0 files unresolved

So it's checking out 4404 files, but removes 21 less. Since these 21 files were left behind, I can investigate what makes them so special.